# Does android clear local variable when app is on background

Tags: android, crash, garbage-collection, onresume

I seem to be getting a crash once my app goes in background for some time . Does it clear all local variables.

Answer (score 1):

Member variables in your class does not clear unless the class is garbage collected.

I assume you are referring to variables in a Activity class and then you have to take into account the Activity lifecycle used in Android.

Please check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#StartingAnActivity) you can see that the system can destroy your paused activity if it needs the Memory. Also, the Garbage collector will remove variables even if no active thread has access to this variable (i.e. even if the Activity is not destroyed, but a variable created by a thread that is not active). You need to handle `onPause()` to save your data persistently if you need to keep it.